# Modern pages layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

In my regular team site the home.aspx page is not updated to modern automatically. But if I create a new modern page it gets a large header field with the page name (see below). Quite ugly indeed.

- Is there a way to get a front page that looks like a group team site on a regular team site? Ie without the large gray page name field and a wider news web part (notice the width difference of the news web part on the group team site compared to the regular team site in the pictures below).

The first image in this article show a group team site. It has a webpart that displays three news items in a row as cards.

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2016/05/Modern-Team-Sites-Pages-Apps.html

- I can't find a news web part that show three card items in a row as shown in the article?

Regular teamsite
[image]

Group teamsite
[image]

Comment: So I found an blog where someone from MS said the layout pictures in the article I linked is just renders and might never be implemented that way.

Concerning the front page it seems it will be implemented, it just hasn't happened yet. Still unconfirmed though. Still no idea why the news web part renders different width in different team sites.